# Google Chrome 'onLaunched' error in plugin

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am following the google chrome web app development on http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/first_app.html and the web app is not launching. when i click on the app icon on the page it closes the tab. I have downloaded the sample apps and plugins from github but they too are not working when i look at the console i get this error, please not i have enabled experimental API's in chrome://flags.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onLaunched' of undefined
```

I have updated my chrome browser to version 22.0.1229.79. My manifest.json file is

```
{
"name": "Hello World!",
"description": "My first packaged app.",
"manifest_version": 2,

"version": "0.1",
"app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "calculator-16.png", 
    "128": "calculator-128.png"
}
```

}

And my background.js file

```
   chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'width': 400,
        'height': 500
    });
});
```

Can someone point me where am going wrong?

Comment: I had a similar issue ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647445/chrome-plugin-not-initializing-properly)) that seemed to be resolved when I rebooted the browser. I had been running many tabs and the browser had been open for a while.

Comment: I ended up changing my manifest to look like this `{
    "name": "Qlipe",
    "description": "Qlipe Chrome app",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    
    "version": "0.1",
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "local_path": "index.html"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "Qlipe-16.png", 
        "128": "Qlipe-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
    "http://www.qlipe.com/api/feed",
    "http://0.0.0.0:6543/api/feed",
    "unlimitedStorage"
    ]` Note i removed the background js

Comment: Interesting. I'll play with that when I get a chance. Have you tried specifying background.html and embedding the javascript in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a dev/beta copy of [Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) that is at least version 23.

I also had to add the following line to the manifest.json file before I could get the sample to run

```
{
  ...,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This error also occurs if you leave out the `"app": {}` declaration in the manifest.json.

I.e. `"background": { "scripts": [ "background.js" ] },`
Will give this error.

And `"app": { "background": { scripts": ["background.js"] },` will work properly.

Answer (score 3):

The new-style packaged apps (with the `background` key in the `app` section in the manifest) are only supported in Chrome 23 (currently in the dev channel, soon to be in the beta channel) and later.

Comment: when can we expect this to hit stable, and what's the reccomended workaround until then? (to do background pages in a packaged chrome app)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the Chromium Development Calender [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar).