# Chrome plugin not initializing properly

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome plugin,which I defined with the following manifest:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "test",
    "icons": ["icon.png"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

my `background.js` file looks like this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() { 
    console.log('details', chrome.app.getDetails());
});
```

When it loads, I see this error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onLaunched' of undefined
```

I can't figure out why I am not seeing a properly initialized `chrome.app.runtime`.

How do I debug this?

Gene

**UPDATE:**

When I run the following code:

```
console.log("before connection");
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

I see the first log output (`before connection`) but not the second; does this mean that it fails to connect to the browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome 'onLaunched' error in plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645069/google-chrome-onlaunched-error-in-plugin) (no answers yet, but same problem + same environment).

Comment: I also get the same symptom when I modify the manifest to be version 1.

Comment: I don't think that it's a manifest problem, but I don't have time to sort it out now. Debugging hint: Add `"experimental"` flag to permissions, and look into `chrome.experimental.app` or something (at the background page, fiddle with the console). This is just a guess and by no means a guaranteed solution.

Comment: Rebooting the browser seemed to fix the problem; perhaps there is some memory allocation problem that isn't being handled gracefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.app` is undefined because you aren't defining your extension as an app.

Chrome extension can be only **one** of these in the manifest file:
`browser_action`, `page_action`, `theme`, or `app`.

In your manifest you're defining an browser action.

So take a deep breath and read the documentation for the [manifest file](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html).